# IF in php include file which will be closed by another include file

Tags: php

I need to restrict some areas for normal users. I have written the following php code:

```
<?php if (logged_in() == false): ?>
<?php       redirect_to("../members/login.php?msg=You+have+to+login+first"); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php if(checkrole('superadmin') || checkrole('admin')): ?>
//Normal code like HTML mixed with PHP and so on..
<?php else: ?>
<?php include("../error/403.php");   ?>
<?php endif ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

This code works without any problems. 
When i put the code above the //normal code in an include file and the code below the //normal code in an include file it will looks like this:

```
<?php include("../includes/restrict_begin.php"); ?>
//Normal code like HTML mixed with PHP and so on..
<?php include("../includes/restrict_end.php"); ?>
```

Of course I get an error in the `restrict_begin.php` file:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in ..\includes\restrict_begin.php on line 4
```

Is there a work around to avoid this message and i can use the includes? I have quite a lot of things where I need to implement this code and if a have new userroles I would have to rewrite the code in every single file...

I hope there is a solution.

Comment: Why do you have the opening and closing php tags on each line?

Comment: @foxygen it really hurts my eyes...

Comment: Well the error is quite clear, something is wrong with `../includes/restrict_begin.php`. Perhaps you should provide the source code of that file?

Comment: The trick you tried is not allowed in PHP any more since PHP 4 (back in 2002 or so).

Comment: Maybe you should try the other way :
Have the code in the //normal included from a different file, and the if/elses in the 'main' file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put something like this in `restrict_begin.php`:

```
<?php
if (logged_in() == false) {
    redirect_to("../members/login.php?msg=You+have+to+login+first");
    exit();
}

if (! (checkrole('superadmin') || checkrole('admin'))) {
    include("../error/403.php");
    exit();
}
```

Remove `restrict_end.php`.

That's all you need.